# Delete only consecutive duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have collected data from an API to build a history. Initially, I saved *all* values every five minutes. Later, I changed my program to only save data that has changed.

Now, I want to clean up my old data and remove all values where the `count` has not changed from the previous record within the same `account` and `id`.

```
account id      count   time
42      12147   492     2015-09-20 11:31:14.0
42      12147   492     2015-09-20 11:36:19.0 // delete
13      12147   246     2015-09-20 11:31:14.0
2       12253   183     2015-09-20 11:36:19.0
2       19684   805     2015-09-20 12:00:41.0 // note in next comment
2       19684   810     2015-09-20 12:05:41.0
2       19684   805     2015-09-20 12:10:41.0 // we had this combination, but do not delete this record because the previous value was different
2       19684   805     2015-09-20 12:15:41.0 // delete
2       19684   805     2015-09-20 12:20:41.0 // delete
2       19684   806     2015-09-20 12:25:41.0
```

I tried to solve this with a `group by` over `account`, `id` and `count`. With that approach, however, it will delete *non-consecutive* duplicates—i.e., if a record has the same value again after some time, it will fall into the same group.

I also thought about writing a small script where I iterate over all data and delete the current row if `account`, `id`, and `count` are the same as the previous record, but I'm curious if this be possible with an single SQL statement?

Comment: The third row is another `account` therefore it is in ascending order, isn't it?

Comment: SQL supports the notion of comparing the values in one row to the value from the previous one using a combination of LAG() and QUALIFY. See solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
DELETE history 
FROM history 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(time) AS minTime, account, id, count
            FROM history
            GROUP BY account, id, count) AS h
ON history.account = h.account AND history.id = h.id AND history.count = h.count
WHERE history.time > h.minTime
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f529d/1)

**EDIT:**

After the edit made I think there are still some errors in sample data of the OP (`time` field should be in acending order).

Using an additional assumption of a PK present in the table, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT pk
FROM history AS h1
WHERE account = (SELECT account 
                 FROM history AS h2
                 WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                       h1.id = h2.id AND                       
                       h2.time < h1.time
                 ORDER BY time DESC 
                 LIMIT 1)
      AND
      id = (SELECT id 
            FROM history AS h2
            WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                  h1.id = h2.id AND                  
                  h2.time < h1.time
            ORDER BY time DESC 
            LIMIT 1)
      AND
      count = (SELECT count
               FROM history AS h2
               WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                     h1.id = h2.id AND                     
                     h2.time < h1.time
               ORDER BY time DESC 
               LIMIT 1)
```

in order to identify *to-de-deleted* records (see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f88/4)).

Now you can easily delete unwanted rows using `NOT IN` operator:

```
DELETE FROM history 
WHERE pk IN (
SELECT x.pk
FROM (             
  SELECT pk
  FROM history AS h1
  WHERE 
     account = (SELECT account 
                FROM history AS h2
                WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                      h1.id = h2.id AND                       
                      h2.time < h1.time
                      ORDER BY time DESC 
                      LIMIT 1)

     AND

     id = (SELECT id 
           FROM history AS h2
           WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                 h1.id = h2.id AND                  
                 h2.time < h1.time
           ORDER BY time DESC 
           LIMIT 1)

     AND

     count = (SELECT count
              FROM history AS h2
              WHERE h1.account = h2.account AND
                    h1.id = h2.id AND                     
                    h2.time < h1.time
              ORDER BY time DESC 
              LIMIT 1)) AS x)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74a11/1)

**EDIT 2:**

Using variables in order to located to-de-deleted `pk` values might lead to query that is considerably faster:

```
SELECT pk
FROM (
  SELECT pk, account, id, count, time,
         @rn := IF (account = @acc AND id = @id AND count = @count,
                    @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
         @acc := account,
         @id := id,
         @count := count
  FROM history
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn = 0, @acc = 0, @id = 0, @count = 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY account, id, time, count ) AS t
WHERE t.rn > 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f88/8)

Comment: Great thing with the demo. But there's the problem with the account 2 id19684 which was 805 then rised to 810 and back to 805. These are all valid changes. But then only the next two 805 should be deleted and not the first one but after 810 there's the 806.

Comment: I just saw that I marked one row too much for deletion in my question. Edited it. Sorry...

Comment: @dasKeks I have edited my answer, It should work now.

Comment: I added a pk and generally that seems to work. But a statement with three sub selects per row on a 700.000 row table might be not that fast. I wish one could see the progress for a single sql statement.

Comment: Yes, you are right about performance. If this is a one-time execution statement this shouldn't be such a big problem though. Using variables so as to simulate window functions might lead to a more efficient solution.

Comment: @dasKeks Please check the edit I made. Does this query perform faster compared to the previous one?

Comment: Determining all pks took about 70 seconds which is quiet fast. Deletion will take some more time as it seems but I think that's as fast as I can get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Valuing clarity, this is what I would recommend if one of my reports were trying to do this:

```
select *
from mytable
QUALIFY LAG(count, -1) OVER(PARTITION BY account, id ORDER BY time) != count
```

This returns the table without rows where the count from one row is the same as the count from the last one within the same account and id.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all but the first with this (untested) code:

```
delete from history h1 
where exists (select h2 
              from history 
              where
                h1.account = h2.account and
                h1.id = h2.id and
                h1.count = h2.count and
                h1.time < h2.time
             )
```

Comment: I think is `h1.time *>* h2.time`, because OP want keep the older record

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, this just appears to delete _duplicates_, regardless of whether or not they’re _consecutive_. The consecutive part is what makes this question tricky—and different from a dozen previous Stack Overflow questions.